# Запись данных из бд MySql в label Unknown Column

Tags: c#, mysql

Не могу понять почему при открытии программы выдает ошибку Unknown Column 'Логин' in where clause"

---

```
     DbDataReader dataReader1 = null;
                MySqlCommand cmd12 = new MySqlCommand("SELECT login FROM login WHERE Логин", sqlConnection);
                try
                {
                    //Create a data reader and Execute the command
                    dataReader1 = await cmd12.ExecuteReaderAsync();

                    if (dataReader1.FieldCount > 0)
                    {
                        while (dataReader1.Read())
                        {
                            label1.Text += dataReader1["Староста"].ToString();
                            label1.Text += dataReader1["Группа"].ToString();
                            label1.Text += dataReader1["Дата"].ToString();
                        }
                    }


                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Ошибка!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (dataReader1 != null && !dataReader1.IsClosed)
                    {
                        dataReader1.Close(); // закрываем reader
                    }
                }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если вы уверены, что не допустили какую-то банальную ошибку при создании таблицы (покажите ваш create table), то запишите имя столбца в квадратных скобках: `[Логин]`. PS А, у вас mysql... Тогда экранируйте при помощи апострофа: `

Comment: Ругается на синтаксис

Comment: Мгм, так у вас реально нет столбца "Логин", у вас "login"

Comment: В структуре таблицы `login` действительно нет поля `Логин`.

Comment: @Akina Я пробывал менять местами, одна и таже ошибка

Comment: Предполагаю, что запрос должен выглядеть так: `"SELECT * FROM login WHERE login = 'Логин'"` PS. В слове "пробовал" нет буквы "ы". Или там пропущена буква "ё"?

Comment: И ещё одна ошибка: ваш код читает столбцы в количестве трёх штук (Староста, Группа, Дата), но вы запрашиваете только один - Login!

Comment: @Akina Вы помогли

Comment: @A K как исправить

Comment: Кстати, поле login по смыслу должно быть уникальным, т.е. не допускать дубликатов значений.